# Groovy - ClassCastException accessing property

Tags: groovy

Groovy:   2.5.15
Java:      11

I have a java class:

```
@Data
public class SpecialDTO {
   Long originId;
}
```

But, when I access it from my Groovy code:

```
Long myId = specialdto.originId
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class SpecialDTO cannot be cast to class groovy.lang.GroovyObject (SpecialDTO and groovy.lang.GroovyObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Which appears bogus as I can insert this in the code and it works:

```
GroovyObject obj = specialdto
```

We do this all over the place, but this specific test is failing.    I can substitute 'getOriginId()' and get the desired results, but it's just such an odd error given that it only happens with this object.

Comment: What is it `@Data` ?

Comment: @daggett that would be lombok on a Java object.   It creates setters, getters, equals, etc.

Comment: so. lombok and groovy could be considered as competitors because groovy itself adds getter and setters...

Comment: All true and Lombok doesn't support Groovy period.   The SpecialDTO is located in a Java file, and the other code is groovy code calling this Java object.